# How do Hidden Markov models classify sequential data?

Tags: classification, markov-process, hidden-markov-model, graphical-model, sequential-pattern-mining

How exactly do HMMs classify sequential data? I understand that this is a generative model, which models the joint probability distribution and provides us with the conditional probability of generating the observation sequence by the HMM. I also understand that there are three distinct problems that need to be solved. One being the evaluation problem, which involves making use of the Forward-Backward algorithm to evaluate the likelihood of the model given the observations.

For example if we are considering a binary classification task, where we are trying to classify a sequence of transactions to be either fraudulent or non-fraudulent, the HMM will provide us with a probability that the transaction is, say, non-fraudulent.

What I am confused about is once the system is ready to output the likelihood of for example the transaction being non-fraudulent, do we then have to specify a decision rule to determine what probability is classified as a non-fraud transaction and what is fraudulent? Or is this already done by the HMM itself?

Apologies in advance if this is a trivial question – I am quite new to this field.

Comment: There are a few alternatives but the most common is the Viterbi algorithm. https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=Viterbi